# Force select a jQuery-ui-tab as default

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

At the moment, I have 2 separate functions which create tabs in the jquery tabs ui.  It seems a bit random as to which tab generated from these 2 functions ends up being the tab which displays by default.

For example, if `function tabs_a` create 4 tabs, and `function tabs_b` create another 4 tabs, either the first tab from `tabs_a` is displayed as the default tab or the first tab from `tabs_b` is displayed as default.

How do I chose to display/select a specific tab automatically once both functions have finished loading/create the tabs?

For example, if function `tabs_a` creates:

```
tab_a_1
tab_a_2
tab_a_3
tab_a_4
```

and tabs_b creates:

```
tab_b_1
tab_b_2
tab_b_3
tab_b_4
```

at the moment, `tab_a_1` or `tab_b_1` will get selected by default, and it seems random which one of these 2 ends up getting selected by default.

How do I for example force `tab_b_3` to become selected by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the tabs are created, you can forcefully call the following

```
$("#tabs").tabs('select', "#tab_b_3");
```

Here, `#tabs` is the id of the div on which you have called the `.tabs()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the 'select' method was removed from jQuery UI in v1.9. To accomplish what you're looking to do, just use the 'active' option to set the active tab:

```
$('#tab_b').tabs({ active: true });
```

OR

```
$('#tab_b').tabs('option', 'active', true);
```

Comment: It looks like jQuery UI updated the api for "active" so it needs to be a boolean:

`$('#tab_b').tabs({ active: true });`

Answer (score -1):

After creating the tabs.

//force select the tab
$("#tab_b").tabs("select", "tab_b_2");

Check it out here
http://jsfiddle.net/75XFM/3/

Or check the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#tab_a").tabs();
$("#tab_b").tabs();
//force select the tab  
$("#tab_b").tabs("select", "tab_b_2");
</script> 


<div id="tab_a">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab_a_1">TabA1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab_a_2">TabA2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab_a_3">TabA3</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab_a_1">I'm Tab A1</div>
    <div id="tab_a_2">I'm Tab A2</div>
    <div id="tab_a_3">I'm Tab A3</div>
</div>
<div id="tab_b">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab_b_1">TabA1</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab_b_2">TabA2</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab_b_3">TabA3</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab_b_1">I'm Tab A1</div>
    <div id="tab_b_2">I'm Tab A2</div>
    <div id="tab_b_3">I'm Tab A3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does not work in the year 2020. :-(. Neither does the fiddle.